# How can I optimize creating an xlsx file?

Tags: javascript, python, django, xlsx, xls

I have created an API that reads a file we recieve and then gives me back the information I need. I now need to create a new .xlsx file with this new data I have recieved.

Currently it's working, but it is really not optimized. Creating a file with 4000 lines pretty much instant, but we will need to create files with up to hundreds of thousands of lines. At the moment, creating a file with 140,000 lines took 14 minutes.

I am not very experienced in algoritm optimization so i'm not sure where look for optimizing.

This is a project written with a Django backend. Here is the views.py function

```
def vannmiljo(request):
    survey_id = request.GET.get('surveyID', None)
    if not survey_id:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'SurveyID parameter is missing'}, status=400)
    
    instanceID = request.GET.get('m_instanceID', None)
    if not instanceID:
        error = "No datafile"
        return JsonResponse({'error': error}, status=400)
    
    instance = SurveyInstance.objects.get(id=instanceID)
    if not instance.survey_file:
        error = "No datafile"
        return JsonResponse({'error': error}, status=400)
    else:
        excel_file_url = instance.get_survey_file_url

    response = requests.get(excel_file_url) 
    if not response.status_code == 200:
        print(f'Failed to download Excel file: {response.status_code}')
    excel_data = BytesIO(response.content)

    try:
        dfs = pd.read_excel(excel_data, engine="openpyxl")

        start_row = dfs[dfs.eq('Sal.').any(axis=1)].index[0]
        dfs = dfs.iloc[start_row:]

        dfs.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        dfs.columns = dfs.iloc[0]
        dfs = dfs[1:]

        data_list = []
        columns_to_keep = [col for col in ["Sal.", "Cond.", "Temp", "Ox %", "mg/l", "T (FTU)", "Density", "S. vel.", "Depth(dp)", "Date", "Time"] if col in dfs.columns]

        # Create a new DataFrame with only the necessary columns
        filtered_dfs = dfs[columns_to_keep].copy()

        # Rename the columns to the desired names
        column_renames = {
            "Sal.": "sal", 
            "Cond.": "cond", 
            "Temp": "temp", 
            "Ox %": "ox", 
            "mg/l": "mg_l", 
            "T (FTU)": "t_ftu", 
            "Density": "density", 
            "S. vel.": "s_vel", 
            "Depth(dp)": "depth", 
            "Date": "date", 
            "Time": "time"
        }
        filtered_dfs.rename(columns=column_renames, inplace=True)

        # Convert DataFrame to a list of dictionaries (if needed)
        data_list = filtered_dfs.to_dict('records')

        survey_instance = get_object_or_404(Survey, SurveyID=survey_id)
        survey_details = survey_instance.addInfoID_fk
        approver = survey_details.get_approver
        approver_organization = approver.organisation
        approver_org_name = approver_organization.org_name if approver_organization else None 
        oppdragsgiver = approver_org_name
        oppdragstaker = approver_org_name
        data = {
            'oppdragsgiver': oppdragsgiver,
            'oppdragstaker': oppdragstaker,
            'surveyID': survey_id,
            'data_list': data_list,
        }
        print(data)
    except Exception as e:
        # Catch any exception and return a response indicating the issue
        return HttpResponse(f"Error: {str(e)}", status=500)



    def stream_data():
        yield '{'
        yield f'"oppdragsgiver": "{data["oppdragsgiver"]}",'
        yield f'"oppdragstaker": "{data["oppdragstaker"]}",'
        yield f'"surveyID": "{data["surveyID"]}",'
        yield '"data_list": ['
        first = True
        for item in data['data_list']:
            # Convert datetime and time objects to strings
            for key, value in item.items():
                if isinstance(value, (datetime.datetime, datetime.time)):
                    item[key] = value.isoformat()
            # Add a comma before each item except the first one
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                yield ','
            yield json.dumps(item)
        yield ']}'


    response = StreamingHttpResponse(stream_data(), content_type='application/json')
    
    return response
```

Here is the frontend JS code

```
function createDataToSend(data, oppdragsgiver, oppdragstaker) {
    const parameter_mapping = {
        'cond': 'KOND',
        'density': 'DENS',
        's_vel': 'SOUNDVEL',
        'sal': 'SALIN',
        't_ftu': 'TURB',
        'temp': 'TEMP',
        'ox': 'O2',
        'mg_l': 'MGL'

    };

    const enhet_id_mapping = {
        'cond': 'ms/m',
        'density': 'density',
        's_vel': 'm/s',
        'sal': 'ppt',
        't_ftu': 'FNU',
        'temp': '°C',
        'ox': 'mg/l',
        'mg_l': 'mg/l'
    };

    const dataToSend = [];
    if(data !== undefined){
        data.forEach(item => {
            const parameters = ['cond', 'density', 's_vel', 'sal', 't_ftu', 'temp', 'ox', 'mg_l'];
            parameters.forEach(parameter => {
                if (item[parameter] !== undefined) {
                    const obj = {
                        "Vannlok_kode": "001",
                        "Aktivitet_id": "A123",
                        "Oppdragsgiver": oppdragsgiver,
                        "Oppdragstaker": oppdragstaker,
                        "Medium_id": "Saltvann",
                        "Parameter_id": parameter_mapping[parameter],
                        "Provetakingsmetode_id": "Method1",
                        "Filtrert_Prove": "False",
                        "UnntasKlassifisering" : "", 
                        "Analysemetode_id": "Analysis1",
                        "Operator": "=",
                        "Verdi": item[parameter].toString(),
                        "Enhet_id": enhet_id_mapping[parameter],
                        "Provenr": "",
                        "Tid_provetak": new Date(item.date).toISOString().split('T')[0] + ' ' + item.time,
                        "Ovre_dyp": item.depth.toString(),
                        "Nedre_dyp": item.depth.toString(),
                        "Dybdeenhet": "m",
                        "Ant_verdier": "",
                        "Kommentar": "",
                        "Deteksjonsgrense": "",
                        "Kvantifiseringsgrense": "",
                        "ID_lokal" : "",
                    };
                    dataToSend.push(obj);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    dataToSend.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.Parameter_id < b.Parameter_id) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a.Parameter_id > b.Parameter_id) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    return dataToSend;
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.downloadBtn').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const surveyID = this.getAttribute('data-survey-id');
            const instanceID = this.getAttribute('data-instance-id');
            console.log('Clicked surveyID:', surveyID, 'instanceID:', instanceID);

            fetch(`/surveys/survey/vannmiljo/?surveyID=${surveyID}&m_instanceID=${instanceID}`)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(text => {
                const data = text.split('\n').filter(line => line).map(JSON.parse);
                return data;  
            })
            .then(data => {
                const dataObject = data[0]; 
                const oppdragsgiver = dataObject.oppdragsgiver; 
                const oppdragstaker = dataObject.oppdragstaker; 
                console.log('Oppdragsgiver:', oppdragsgiver, 'Oppdragstaker:', oppdragstaker);
            
                if (!Array.isArray(dataObject.data_list)) { 
                    console.error('data.data_list is not an array');
                    return;
                }
            
                const dataToSend = createDataToSend(dataObject.data_list, oppdragsgiver, oppdragstaker); // Modify this line
                
                
                if (dataObject.data_list && dataObject.data_list.length > 0) {

                    if (Array.isArray(dataToSend) && dataToSend.length > 0) {
                        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/generate-excel', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify({ data: dataToSend }),
                        })
                        .then(response => response.blob())
                        .then(blob => {
                            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            const a = document.createElement('a');
                            a.href = url;
                            a.download = "survey_data.xlsx"; 
                            document.body.appendChild(a);
                            a.click();
                            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                        })
                    } else {
                        console.log('No data to send 1');
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('No data to send 2');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```
export const generateExcel = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        return;
    }

    const data: any[] = req.body.data; 
    

    if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
        console.error('Data is not an array');
        res.status(400).send('Invalid data format');
        return;
    }
    
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Survey Data');
    worksheet.columns = [
        { header: 'Vannlokasjon', key: 'Vannlok_kode', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Aktivitet_id', key: 'Aktivitet_id', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Oppdragsgiver', key: 'Oppdragsgiver', width: 30 },
        { header: 'Oppdragstaker ', key: 'Oppdragstaker', width: 30 },
        { header: 'Parameter' , key: 'Parameter_id', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Medium' , key: 'Medium_id', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Provetakingsmetode' , key: 'Provetakingsmetode_id', width: 25 },
        { header: 'Filtrert Prøve' , key: 'Filtrert_Prove', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Unntas Klassifisering' , key: 'UnntasKlassifisering', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Analysemetode' , key: 'Analysemetode_id', width: 25 },
        { header: 'Operator' , key: 'Operator', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Verdi', key: 'Verdi', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Enhet', key: 'Enhet_id', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Prøve nr' , key: 'Provenr', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Tid Prøvetaking', key: 'Tid_provetak' , width: 30 },
        { header: 'Øvre dyp', key: 'Ovre_dyp', width: 15 },
        { header: 'Nedre dyp', key: 'Nedre_dyp', width: 15 },
        { header: 'Dybdeenhet' , key: 'Dybdeenhet', width: 12 },
        { header: 'Antall verdier' , key: 'Ant_verdier', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Kommentar' , key: 'Kommentar', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Deteksjonsgrense' , key: 'Deteksjonsgrense', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Kvantifiseringsgrense' , key: 'Kvantifiseringsgrense', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Lokal ID' , key: 'ID_lokal', width: 20 },

    ];


    const headerRow = worksheet.getRow(1);
    headerRow.height = 20; 

    headerRow.eachCell((cell, number) => {
    cell.font = { bold: true };
    cell.border = {
        bottom: { style: 'thin', color: { argb: '000000' } }
    };
    });

    worksheet.addRows(data);

    worksheet.eachRow((row, rowNumber) => {
        row.eachCell((cell, colNumber) => {
            cell.border = {
                top: { style: 'thin', color: { argb: '000000' } },
                left: { style: 'thin', color: { argb: '000000' } },
                bottom: { style: 'thin', color: { argb: '000000' } },
                right: { style: 'thin', color: { argb: '000000' } }
            };
        });
    });
    try {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=survey_data.xlsx');
        
        await workbook.xlsx.write(res);
        res.end();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('An error occurred while generating the Excel file.');
    }
};


export const surveyValidationRules = [
    body('data.*.Vannlok_kode').notEmpty().withMessage('Vannlok_kode is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Aktivitet_id').notEmpty().withMessage('Aktivitet_id is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Oppdragsgiver').notEmpty().withMessage('Oppdragsgiver is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Oppdragstaker').notEmpty().withMessage('Oppdragstaker is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Parameter_id').notEmpty().withMessage('Parameter_id is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Medium_id').notEmpty().withMessage('Medium_id is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Provetakingsmetode_id').notEmpty().withMessage('Provetakingsmetode_id is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Analysemetode_id').notEmpty().withMessage('Analysemetode_id is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Operator').notEmpty().withMessage('Operator is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Verdi').notEmpty().withMessage('Verdi is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Enhet_id').notEmpty().withMessage('Enhet_id is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Tid_provetak').notEmpty().withMessage('Tid_provetak is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Ovre_dyp').notEmpty().withMessage('Ovre_dyp is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Nedre_dyp').notEmpty().withMessage('Nedre_dyp is required and cannot be empty'),
    body('data.*.Dybdeenhet').notEmpty().withMessage('Dybdeenhet is required and cannot be empty'),

]






As it seems this function's runtime is performing badly, there must be something I can improve.
```

Comment: You're not showing `generate-excel`, it looks like? Anyway, as usual: have you measured where the most time is being taken with a profiler (your browser's for the frontend code, e.g. Django Debug Toolbar for the backend)?

Comment: If you find it's `json.dumps()` that's taking a lot of time, you can switch to `orjson` (which also handily formats datetimes as ISO8601 for you, so you don't need to do that by hand).

Comment: Yes I did forget to add `generate-excel`, I edited the post now to add it.

Comment: Wait, why do you have a Node.js backend server generating XLSX? You can just as well do that in Python too (or even the frontend!)

Comment: So this will later be used in other parts of the application, so I thought creating a simple API for it would make it more reusable

Comment: As I see it, you're downloading JSON from Django, then uploading that back to another API and then getting XLSX back – moving those 140,000 lines will take its own sweet time too...